# Android - How do you scale views to fit a full screen application's height and width perfectly?

Tags: android

If you have a calculator app and you want to write a layout that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBXwX.png), how do you scale the buttons and display to fit on all screen sizes?

Ideas I have looked into:

1. Programatically calculating the height and width of each component. Programatically creating the views gives you the most power, but is not exactly ideal. I'd prefer to write my UI in XML.
2. Nesting LinearLayouts with Layout weights. This works, but lint gives performance warnings because I am nesting weights. On top of that, it does not take into account text size. So on small screens, text is chopped off. Conversely, on large screens, text is too small.

EDIT:
3. Using a TableLayout with nested weights. Considering these extend from LinearLayout, I assume the lack of lint warnings is irrelevant, this is still going to cause a loss in performance right?

Is there a better way? I feel like I am missing something obvious

**EDIT 2:
In case anyone is interested in the solution for this, I have created a custom layout (as raphw suggested) and will post the source code here:**

EvenSpaceGridLayout.java:

```
package com.example.evenspacegridlayout;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class EvenSpaceGridLayout extends ViewGroup {

    private int mNumColumns;

    public EvenSpaceGridLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public EvenSpaceGridLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                R.styleable.EvenSpaceGridLayout);
        try {
            mNumColumns = a.getInteger(
                    R.styleable.EvenSpaceGridLayout_num_columns, 1);
        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

        // Calculate how many cells we need
        int cellCount = countCellsNeeded();

        // Calculate number of rows needed given the number of cells
        int numRows = cellCount / mNumColumns;

        // Calculate width/height of each individual cell
        int cellWidth = widthSize / mNumColumns;
        int cellHeight = heightSize / numRows;

        // Measure children
        measureChildrenViews(cellWidth, cellHeight);

        setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        final int count = getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
            child.layout(lp.x, lp.y, lp.x + child.getMeasuredWidth(), lp.y + child.getMeasuredHeight());
        }
    }

    private int countCellsNeeded() {

        int cellCount = 0;
        final int childCount = getChildCount();

        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {

            View child = getChildAt(i);
            LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();

            int spanColumns = lp.spanColumns;

            // If it's trying to span too far, make it span the maximum possible
            if (spanColumns > mNumColumns) {
                spanColumns = mNumColumns;
            }

            int remainingCellsInRow = mNumColumns - (cellCount % mNumColumns);
            if (remainingCellsInRow - spanColumns < 0) {
                cellCount += remainingCellsInRow + spanColumns;
            } else {
                cellCount += spanColumns;
            }
        }

        // Round off the last row
        if ((cellCount % mNumColumns) != 0) {
            cellCount += mNumColumns - (cellCount % mNumColumns);
        }

        return cellCount;
    }

    private void measureChildrenViews(int cellWidth, int cellHeight) {

        int cellCount = 0;
        final int childCount = getChildCount();

        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {

            View child = getChildAt(i);
            LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();

            int spanColumns = lp.spanColumns;

            // If it's trying to span too far, make it span the maximum possible
            if (spanColumns > mNumColumns) {
                spanColumns = mNumColumns;
            }

            // If it can't fit on the current row, skip those cells
            int remainingCellsInRow = mNumColumns - (cellCount % mNumColumns);
            if (remainingCellsInRow - spanColumns < 0) {
                cellCount += remainingCellsInRow;
            }

            // Calculate x and y coordinates of the view
            int x = (cellCount % mNumColumns) * cellWidth;
            int y = (cellCount / mNumColumns) * cellHeight;

            lp.x = x;
            lp.y = y;

            child.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(cellWidth * spanColumns, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(cellHeight, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));

            cellCount += spanColumns;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean checkLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams p) {
        return p instanceof LayoutParams;
    }

    @Override
    protected LayoutParams generateDefaultLayoutParams() {
        return new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    }

    @Override
    public LayoutParams generateLayoutParams(AttributeSet attrs) {
        return new LayoutParams(getContext(), attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected LayoutParams generateLayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams p) {
        return new LayoutParams(p.width, p.height);
    }

    public static class LayoutParams extends ViewGroup.LayoutParams {

        int x, y;

        public int spanColumns;

        public LayoutParams(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                    R.styleable.EvenSpaceGridLayout_LayoutParams);
            try {
                spanColumns = a
                        .getInteger(
                                R.styleable.EvenSpaceGridLayout_LayoutParams_span_columns,
                                1);

                // Can't span less than one column
                if (spanColumns < 1) {
                    spanColumns = 1;
                }
            } finally {
                a.recycle();
            }
        }

        public LayoutParams(int w, int h) {
            super(w, h);
        }
    }
}
```

attrs.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <declare-styleable name="EvenSpaceGridLayout">
        <attr name="num_columns" format="integer" />
    </declare-styleable>

    <declare-styleable name="EvenSpaceGridLayout_LayoutParams">
        <attr name="span_columns" format="integer" />
    </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

Usage as follows:

```
<com.example.evenspacegridlayout.EvenSpaceGridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:grid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.evenspacegridlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    grid:num_columns="4" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="CL" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Del" />

    <!-- empty cell -->
    <View 
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="/" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="7" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="8" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="9" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="*" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="4" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="5" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="6" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="-" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="+" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="." />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="0" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="="
        grid:span_columns="2" />

</com.example.evenspacegridlayout.EvenSpaceGridLayout>
```

And the end result:

[image: portrait]
[image: landscape]

Comment: top answers on this one should do it for u.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265804/how-to-create-an-imageview-that-fills-the-parent-height-and-displays-an-image-as

Comment: All 3 answers on this question are ImageView specific

Comment: "On top of that, it does not take into account text size. So on small screens, text is chopped off. Conversely, on large screens, text is too small." That isn't a problem with the LinearLayout approach, that's a problem with what you're trying to do - any solution will have that problem.

Also for the LinearLayout solution, the nested weights are in different dimensions so it shouldn't be a performance issue. Either the warning is dumb or LinearLayout is dumb, not sure which.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply write a `ViewGroup` subclass yourself which does what you want and still use this layout in an *XML* layout definition just as you would use any predefined layout. Alternatively, look at the `GridLayout` class. Maybe this `ViewGroup` implementation already does what you are looking for. (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html) In the end, these `ViewGroup` layouts programatically compute the size of their contained `View` components and if no predefined layout offers the functionality you require, there is no other way than implementing your individual requirements.

However, it should remain the responsibility of the button `View` instances to keep their content within the scope the size they received during their latest call of `onMeasure`.

Nesting layouts to the extend it would be necessary with your example picture and the `LinearLayout` class should indeed be avoided. It should be noted that is nevertheless a common practice since this is done implicitly when using a `TableLayout`.

Comment: GridLayout doesn't quite do what I want. It says in the docs that it doesn't support weight. Creating my own custom layout is an interesting option I hadn't considered. I thought it might have a simpler solution than that.

Comment: It is not as much effort as many people think it is. I was avoiding it for quite a while myself. Now I even do it just to opimize away nested layouts. It is something well worth learning and once you are familiar with it, you might even start considering it as a first option for many things.

Comment: I have read up on creating custom layouts and I agree with you. This is actually surprisingly easy, and definitely the way to go for this problem. Cheers for the suggestion. I'm going to make a layout tonight.

Comment: I posted the source for my custom layout as "Edit 2" in the question if anyone is interested

Answer (score 3):

The `GridLayout` as suggested by someone else is not flexible enough to do this. To do this, use the `android:layout_weight` property. This allows you to fill the available space according to the fractions specified.

**Example with the equal weights:**

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="100dp">
    <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:text="A" />
    <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:text="B" />    
    <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:text="C" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

**Example with different weights:**

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="100dp">
    <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:text="A" />
    <Button android:layout_weight="2" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:text="B" />    
    <Button android:layout_weight="2" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:text="C" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

**More complex example**

Here is a more complex example for a layout like used in a calculator app that uses multiple `LinearLayout`s:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:text="7" />
        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:text="8" />    
        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:text="9" />
        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:text="x" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:text="4" />
        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:text="5" />    
        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:text="6" />
        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:text="-" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:text="1" />
        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:text="2" />    
        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:text="3" />
        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:text="+" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <Button android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:text="0" />
        <Button android:layout_weight="1.5" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:text="." />    
        <Button android:layout_weight="1.5" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:text="=" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: See my 2nd point: "Nesting LinearLayouts with Layout weights. This works, but lint gives performance warnings because I am nesting weights. On top of that, it does not take into account text size. So on small screens, text is chopped off. Conversely, on large screens, text is too small."

This is currently my best solution too, but as you can see from your screenshot, the text does not scale along with the view

Comment: @grandstaish Don't worry about the performance. I use it in my app and it works fine on low-end devices as well. You can make the text scale properly by using different layouts for different screen sizes. It won't be automatic, but it's as close as you'll get non-programmatically.

Comment: True. You wouldn't even need extra layouts, you would just use different styles for different screen sizes (i.e. define a different textSize in each style directory). This is looking like the best solution. I will mark it as an answer tomorrow unless anyone else comes up with something